# Merging rows with common values

Tags: text-processing, perl

I am trying to combine pairwise matches in a text file so that i can find all matches in a group: e.g.

my file contains two tab separated columns like this:

```
Simon John
Simon Paul
Steve Simon
Graham Dave
Dave Jason
Paul Simon
Peter Derek
```

And i would like a file outputting the groups, e.g.

```
Simon John Paul Steve
Graham Dave Jason
Peter Derek
```

Any help would be really useful!! I have tried the below script, but i appear to get duplicate matches (e.g. Simon would appear twice on separate rows in out file), and it takes a long time  to run. Ideally if there is a away to do it in bash would be best.

```
use strict;

my(@homologs,$genefile,@temp,$line,$found,$i,$j);

$genefile="Arabidopsis_combined.txt";

open(IN,"<$genefile") or die "cannot open $genefile\n";
$j=0;
while(!eof(IN)){
    $line=readline *IN;
    chomp($line);
    @temp=split /\t/,$line;
    $i=0;
    $found="F";
    while($i<@homologs){
        if($temp[0]~~@{$homologs[$i]}){
            if($temp[1]~~@{$homologs[$i]}){}
            else{push @{$homologs[$i]},$temp[1];}
            $found="T"; 
            }
        if($temp[1]~~@{$homologs[$i]}){
            if($temp[0]~~@{$homologs[$i]}){}
            else{push @{$homologs[$i]},$temp[0];}
            $found="T";         
            }
        $i++;       
        }
    if($found eq "F"){
        push @homologs,[@temp];
        }
    print $j."\n";
    $j++;
    }
close(IN);

print "Number of groups of homologs: ".@homologs."\n";

open(OUT,">homologs.txt");
$i=0;
while($i<@homologs){
    print OUT "@{$homologs[$i]}"."\n";
    $i++;   
    }
close(OUT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard problem of finding connected components in an undirected graph.  Since you tagged your question with `perl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10;                                       
use strict;
use warnings;

use Graph::Undirected;

my $g = Graph::Undirected->new;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $g->add_edge( split /\t/ );
}

for ( $g->connected_components() ) {
    say join ' ', @$_;
}
```

Or its command-line equivalent:

```
perl -MGraph::Undirected -F'\t' -lane '
  BEGIN{$g=Graph::Undirected->new}
  $g->add_edge(@F);
  END{$,=" ";print @$_ for $g->connected_components}'
```